# Calling mmap from inside function in C

Tags: c, memory-management, mmap, memset

I have recently start playing with mmap and memory segments. I want to call mmap from inside function but I have problems to get it working. I can call mmap from main and it works. I know it's about pointers but I feel like I am missing some pieces.

main:

```
int main(){

    char test[100];
    memset(test, 0xCC, 100);
    get_space(NULL,sizeof(test), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, (void**)&test);

    return 0;
}
```

get_space function:

```
void get_space(void **vaddr, unsigned int size, unsigned int flags, void **source){
    void *destination;

    destination = mmap(vaddr,size,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE,-1,0);
    memcpy(destination, source, size);

//...
}
```

I found few threads about it an nice documentation about mmap but still did not work it out. Your help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: "not work" is not a very helpful problem description. Does it crash? Does it produce wrong results? Does it get a compile error? What?

Comment: `get_space()` should return the pointer to the shared memory.

Comment: Your `get_space()` function doesn't make sense. It doesn't "get a space". Don't you want to return the pointer you obtain with `mmap()`?

Also, you're not using your `source` parameter at all; and - the address of `test` is not a pointer-to-a-pointer - it is a pointer to the first element of `test`, i.e. a `char*`.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly this code is supposed to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. This is just a draft of my code without unnecessary functions. What I want to do: I want to allocate memory inside function get_space() and fill it with source data. vaddr is a point from which I want to allocate memory. If I manage to start mmap function properly then I will later on take care of returning it to main function. At this moment code is compiling but it crash at memcpy with segfault. For me it seems like mmap does not allocate memory correctly due to bad pointers. I have changed code. Please check it again.

Comment: ps. if vaddr is NULL then mmap will allocate first available memory.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that mmap must have rised flag MAP_ANNONYMOUS when you are not using file descriptor FD. Solved :)